# Passing values to checkboxes array

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

How can I pass some values to the different elements of the array ussing checkboxes.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="carga[]" value="5.62"> <!-- this value "5.62" -->
<input type="checkbox" name="carga[]" value="4.5">
<input type="checkbox" name="carga[]" value="3.37">
```

PHP:

```
$cargaacademica=$_POST["carga"];

for ($i=0;$i<count($cargaacademica);$i++)    
{     
echo "<br> Carga " . $i . ": " . $cargaacademica[$i];    
}
```

Comment: do you want to get the user input (or just have a list of all the values in an array) or do you want to generate the radio buttons? what's your purpose?

Comment: In PHP you did this in first line:
$cargaacademica=$_POST["carga"];
Write, what do you want as result.

Comment: I want to have only the user input if the user check the box get the value of the box else get 0 ,I will sum all the values.

Comment: show us all the html code , maybe you have problem in form tag because all what you have done here is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
       $cargaacademica=$_POST["carga"];
       $sum = 0;

       if(!empty($cargaacademica))
       {
            $sum = array_sum($cargaacademica);
       }
       echo $sum;    
?>
```

In **$sum**, you will get sum of all check elements of check-box.